# Calling a function that requires parameters in powershell from the cmd prompt

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will be calling a function.
I will be passing in arguments to this powershell script from the command winows `(start > run > 'cmd' > 'powershell.exe -noexit...')`
I will be passing parameters into that line.  Now, right now I have my function set up to run like this...

```
BackUpDirectories -ProjectName $args[0] -ServerName $args[1] -PW $args[2] -user $args[3]
```

But I can tell when I run this function that the arguments that I passed in are not being used   (because I have an output statement that prints out the variable).  Am I calling that function incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more code would help me see the best path forward . . . but here is something I do.

At the top of my script, I will add whatever parameters I am expecting when that script is executed.

```
param([string]$ProjectName, [string]$ServerName, [string]$PW, [string]$user)

#Your internal function already knows about these values
BackUpDirectories -ProjectName $ProjectName -ServerName $ServerName -PW $PW -user $user
```

Comment: I actually tried that and I am getting an exception... The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  ??? where are you placing that?

Comment: Thanks.  That seemed to help.

Comment: If you need additional assistance, just let me know.  I put the param() at the very top of the script.